# By using Hostinger hosting, facing "MySQL server has gone away"

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am using Hostinger hosting. Recently i install a script of Turbo Website Reviewer. During scanning URL of any website, facing the problem of incomplete result with this error "MySQL server has gone away"

What should I do now?

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Have you seen this: https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/1583503-how-to-fix-the-mysql-server-has-gone-away-error ?

Comment: Contact your hoster.

Comment: your mysql server can't handle the load you put on it

Comment: Additional DB information request from YOUR hostinger website, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 4 hours UPTIME and seeing error message.
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions to minimize timeout's.